# Polling factory in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have write factory where i am fetching the data from json. and plotting to html table .

**my question is how to refresh the data after certain amount of time ?**

my code is as follow

```
.factory('getManagementData', function ($http) {
        return {
            list: function (callback) {
                $http.get('../static/data/management.json').success(callback);

            }
        };

    })

    .controller('getdata',function($scope,getManagementData){
        getManagementData.list(function(data){
            //binding data to html page 
        })

    });
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: Take a look at Angular's [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) service

Comment: @Ankh is spot on . we can achieve polling using `$interval` .

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) or [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval). For example, this code refreshes the data every 5 seconds:

```
.controller('getdata',function($scope, $interval, getManagementData){
    function refreshData() {
        getManagementData.list(function(data){
            //binding data to html page 
        });
    }

    $interval(refreshData, 5000);
});
```